# When developing, why is `pip install .` so much slower than `python setup.py install`?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

While I'm developing a python package, a common loop for me is to edit a few files, then reinstall the package in my virtual environment and re-run tests:

```
python setup.py install && pytest tests
```

The `python setup.py install` part runs in 0.696 seconds.

I feel like I should be using `pip` for this, which also works but is MUCH slower than the previous command:

```
pip install . && pytest tests
```

Here `pip install .` runs in 42.006 seconds.

Is there any way to speed up a local development install of `pip install .` so it's on the order of `python setup.py install`?

Comment: Start by running `pip install . -vvv` and adding the log to the question.

Comment: Also, _edit a few files, then reinstall the package_ could be replaced by installing the package once in the editable mode: `pip install --editable .` will reflect any development changes in source code immediately in the installed package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is slow because it makes a full copy of the entire directory, including possibly big hidden dirs like .git, .hg, .idea, .vagrant etc.

See this open issue: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2195